# Noise from switching fans nearby disrupting the I2C bus

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi

I have a RPi controlling a solar system which uses temperature sensors on the I2C bus, the sensors are away from the RPi (20m). The problem is that I have cooling towers and cooling compressors which have high switching currents. In the beginning I tried the I2C and it did not work at default frequency. So I reduced the frequency which got it working for a while. However whenever some of the fans start working I lose some readings for a couple of seconds and sensors start acting weird.

I think it is a noise problem, especially that my 230VAC power supply is coming from the same 3~ph power supply of the fans.

What would be the best way to protect the signals on the I2C bus? I use now CAT5 cable to wire the sensors. I wanted to use CAT7 but then I read that this will actually make it worse since CAT7 has higher capacitance which is worse for the bus at longer distances.

**More Info:**

I'm using 10kHz currently since the default 100kHz did not work.
On a similar setup however (but without the nearby fans) i got away with 100kHz and more than 20m without extenders or anything. System has been running smoothly for more than 2 years now. That is why i'm thinking it is a noise issue.

Comment: Forget the I2C at this distance and go for something more robust like Profibus or Mbus.

Comment: Did you say that you are using i2c over 20m? Are you using some sort of extender? What SCL clock rate are you using?

Comment: Try running your pi from a battery to isolate power as an issue?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this source](http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/miscellaneous/i2c-bus/frequently-asked-questions/i2c-faq.html) which is an FAQ on I2C bus protocol.

This suggests that typical lengths are 3-4 meters, and with the serial clock running as slow as 500Hz in applications of 100 meters are known to work.

I suggest you lower the clock speed significantly from the standard 100Khz to something like 8-10Khz or something and do some tests.

Also, what I2C bus pull-up resistance do you have? With such a long distance, the bus capacitance must be very high so your resistors should be quite low, maybe 1.8-2K Ohm (as shown further down in the FAQ actually!).

EDIT:

May I suggest going away from wires sensors? You can put together a very simple little package that can act as wireless sensor nodes. Then you can place them 80m away if you really wanted to. And you can have lots of them without worrying too much about running cables everywhere. Depending on your level of skill/embedded systems knowledge, you may want something simple like a Synapse [like those sold at Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11279) which supports all sorts of cool mesh networking too if you wanted. Otherwise you can investigate other more in-depth designs...

Answer (score 4):

IIC is going to be problematic. You are sending a clock signal out to the remote devices and that clock signal (when it arrives) clocks back data to the master and the master reads the data by clocking it back in but the clock the master is now using bears little resemblance to the delayed clock at the sensor and the data coming back is delayed even more. This has to mean running as slow as you can get away with.

Given that you have interference issues I'd suggest running clock and data down coaxial cables - at least try it to see if it helps - it won't help the data be more aligned to the clock at the master but it might stop interference giving you a hard time.

I had to send SPI bus to a remote device at 10m - data was being sent from the master only so both clock and data were properly aligned (cable length same distance) - I was using 2MHz clock but I decided that the only way it would work reliably was with differential drivers and receivers on both clock and data. It worked of course and I might have got away with coax but I'm sure regular unshielded cable and single-ended data and clock wouldn't work reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Go diffrential on the I2C
check out LVDS. In practice it is quite easy, all you need is an IC on each side and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend switching to a different bus and then placing small microcontrollers alongside each sensor to bridge to the I2C bus.  I2C is really not designed to work over that distance, especially since it is an open drain bus.  RS232 (standard serial port, make sure to use a level shifter to get the actual +/- 12 volt levels) and RS485/RS422 (differential, half or full duplex signalling, again make sure to get the right driver chip) will be better able to cope with the interference over a long run.  Also, it would be possible to buffer readings at the sensor so you can just ask for a retransmit if something gets lost.

Wireless is another option, but that brings with it another can of worms - RF interference, multipath, fading, reflections, path losses, etc.  It can sometimes be dicey to get RF working properly when there is a lot of machinery and/or large metal objects where you are trying to communicate.  And you will still need a microcontroller with the sensor to act as a bridge.